# Javascript Side Effects

Tags: javascript

I'm new to the Javascript world, and I'm trying to analyze and clean up some existing code. I'm interested in understanding "side effects" in the code; in some cases, it's obvious to me, but in other cases I'm not sure.

As an example, in the following exported function, is assigning **newProperty** considered a side effect - and **newProperty** will not exist until the code is run, or will the compiler understand and treat this function as an object with a **newProperty** property?

This is of interest to me when considering how webpack will treat this code when it is imported in another file.

```
    export function doSomething(a, b) {
        let c = a + b
        return c
    }
    doSomething.newProperty = () => "someString"
```

Comment: Just add class and remove class for example

Comment: "understand and treat this function as an object" Functions are Objects in javascript.

Comment: i'd recomment you drop this question and focus on learning JavaScript from reputable sources, such as MDN.

Comment: Also javascript in not the best language to understand "side-effects". Almost everything in javascript could cause side-effects. Even your "looking pure" function could launch missiles :)

Comment: "*newProperty will not exist until the code is run*" - yes, exactly.

Comment: @Peter your critics to the OP is quite unfounded, as MDN (which I appreciate a lot in general) on this particular subject has [not too much to say](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_module_for_its_side_effects_only) . Furthermore the OP's example is nontrivial, as any function which mutates an already existing `doSomething` has indeed a side-effect. It is only if one regards the whole module as a function with the exports as kind of return value that it is fair to say it's free of side effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a file is imported, all top level statements are run. Most of the time this just means that functions/classes are declared and exported, but in your code you are also setting a property on the function. That means that the exported function will contain the extra property as soon as the file is imported, *it does not have to be run first.*

Although I think the concept of 'side effects' is a little misguided. Generally, a side effect is when a function alters some external state that is not the intended return value.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an accepted valid answer, so this one should be seen only as an addendum. I'd just like to demonstrate that the question has subtleties related to it. Let me present a very similar example in two slightly different versions, the first analogue to the OP and without side-effect, the second slightly changed and with side-effect:

```
//module array_with_a.js
export const arr = [];
arr[0] = "a";
```

An import of the above module would be free of side effects like in the accepted answer for the original question, because the object becomes available for the importer only after the construction has been completed. However, it becomes tricky, if one decides to split the same thing into two modules:

```
//module empty_array.js
export const arr = [];
```

and

```
//module array_with_a.js
import {arr} from "./empty_array.js";
arr[0] = "a";
export {arr};
```

The last module is still doing exactly the same thing as before. If one would guarantee that the "./empty_array" module is not used anywhere else, it would still be without side effects, but as soon as another module imports the `arr` from "./empty_array.js", the mutation performed within the module "./array_with_a.js" will also affect the array `arr` at other places where it is imported. Hence a side effect.